# Log a string without ending newline

Tags: python, logging, python-3.x

I want to print a debug message (a string) which may or may not contain an ending newline, without the ending newline.

With `print` it's easy:

```
print('asdf\n', end='')
```

However with standard `logging` library there is no `end` parameter and the ending newline gets printed:

```
import logging
logging.warning('asdf\n')
```

What is the best way to print a message without the ending newline in the `logging` library function calls?

Comment: Maybe you can change `warning` method.

Comment: @Reloader You mean overload? There are at least 5 such functions. It won't look very beautiful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can strip 0 or more newlines with [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) *before* passing it to `logging.warning()`:

```
logging.warning(message.rstrip('\n'))
```